# Apache Myfaces prints blank td tag when using h:dataTable and an empty dataset

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, datatable, myfaces

Is there a way to have MyFaces *not* print the following when the List or Array backing an `h:dataTable` is empty?

```html
<table>
    <tbody id="itemsForm:itemsDataTable:tbody_element">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I suspect it would be more correct to print an empty tbody. Can this be overridden somehow?

Comment: Can't you just use `rendered="#{not empty bean.items}"`? Otherwise, a custom renderer is probably your best bet.

Comment: @BalusC I considered that, but I'd still like the column labels to display. On a side note, why aren't the javaee and java tags relavent?

Comment: See the comment in the edit history.

Comment: ....right. sigh. Sometimes stackoverflow really makes me want to beat my head against the desk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those elements are required as per [XHTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html#a_dtd_XHTML-1.0-Transitional). The `<table>` requires *at least one* `<tr>`. The `<tr>` requires in turn *at least one* `<td>`.

```
<!ELEMENT table
     (caption?, (col*|colgroup*), thead?, tfoot?, (tbody+|tr+))>
<!ELEMENT caption  %Inline;>
<!ELEMENT thead    (tr)+>
<!ELEMENT tfoot    (tr)+>
<!ELEMENT tbody    (tr)+>
<!ELEMENT colgroup (col)*>
<!ELEMENT col      EMPTY>
<!ELEMENT tr       (th|td)+>
<!ELEMENT th       %Flow;>
<!ELEMENT td       %Flow;>
```

*(the `+` stands for one or more, the `*` stands for zero or more, the `?` stands for zero or one)*

Your best bet is to hide the table altogether when the data model is empty.

```
<h:dataTable ... value="#{bean.items}" rendered="#{not empty bean.items}">
```

Otherwise, you can't go around a custom renderer.

Comment: I'm using transitional, but I looked at the DTD and it has the same lines. Thanks